# I want to count where cells in the same row are number, text or blank if a cell in a different column is "1" or "2"

Tags: excel, countif

The words to explain this well in the title escaped me, so I'll try to do so here.

I'm trying to count how many cells across three columns (varying number of rows on each sheet) contain one: a number, two: any text, or three: nothing.

I've been counting the totals of cells containing numbers, text or nothing using countifs:

```
=COUNTIF('02_Leavers'!J3:L968,">0")
=COUNTIF('02_Leavers'!J3:L968,"*")
=COUNTIF('02_Leavers'!J3:L968,"")
```

But I now need to split these totals by how many exist where column E is "1", and where column E is "2" (priorities).

Is this possible to do in one cell, without a UDF?

If I've not mentioned anything please ask!

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjsSZ.jpg)

Comment: Try the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED). Use full column references; it will not impact calculation.

Comment: I did try that earlier:    '=COUNTIFS('02_Leavers'!E3:E968,"1",'02_Leavers'!J3:L968,">0")' and I get #VALUE. I don't know if this will work being as the columns J-L can be number, text or blank?

Comment: Sample test data would be helpful for us.

Comment: `J3:L968` has to be `J3:J968` or `L3:L968`. If you need both (three...?) columns checked there are other ways.

Comment: Struggling to find a quick way to give a good sample of data while keeping it confidential... Essentially what I've done is a long winded way, new tab, several cells with `=COUNTIFS('02_Leavers'!E3:E968,"1",'02_Leavers'!J3:J968,">0")` and other criteria and then totaled into one sum for column J, K and L for the above, total called out in the original sheet... Messy and long but it works...

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to build an OR condition where if any of the cells in a row from columns J, K or L are greater than zero then the condition is true. You have to be careful not to count more than a single time of more than one cell in a row is greater than zero (e.g. J3 is 6 and L3 is 10).

A [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) can build the three column conditions and the [SIGN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SIGN-function-cfaaf798-9b34-4569-955c-a74a523a7c4a) can ensure that multiple positives still only count as a single.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('02_Leavers'!$E$3:$E$968=1), SIGN(('02_Leavers'!$J$3:$J$968>0)+('02_Leavers'!$K$3:$K$968>0)+('02_Leavers'!$L$3:$L$968>0)))
```

[image: SUMP_COUNTIF2]

Comment: This looks great, I'm gonna have to use the method I mentioned earlier to push some end of day stats, because I need to do this separately for 12 different workbooks. I'll take a look at this when I'm home tonight, one thing I should probably mention is that I do actually need to count each time a row has a number, because I'm producing the totals (so if there are numbers in two columns, I want it to return 2) same with each time a row contains text, and each time it is blank.

Comment: I've tried this and the totals didn't add up to what I got when using the multiple countifs (I confirmed these were right). I've added an image of some sample data, what I want to do is total the amount of references I have where the priority is 1, and where it is 2. I want to do the same for wherever priority 1 and 2 have text in a cell, and where the cell is blank. so for line 1 i'd want it to add 1 to the total of numbers for priority 2, and 2 to the total of blanks. for the 5th line i'd want it to add 3 to the total of numbers for priority 1. I hope I've explained that ok?